# Tkinter: One large class for entire application

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Good afternoon, StackOverflow community,

I am a first-time GUI coder seeking advice. I am busy with my MSc in Physical Chemistry, for context.

I have a simple question:
**Is it considered poor practice to wrap the entirety of my code into a single class?**
I have tried to split my code up in classes, but I can't seem to get the initialising magic method right when dealing with multiple classes. For reference, I have attached my own **init**. Maybe you could help me understand how I could possibly split all of this up into different classes, which could go into separate modules.

Thanks!

```
class ApplicationUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialises the GUI and parent.
        """
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.create_canvas()
        self.create_menus()
        self.create_main_buttons()

        self.data = {}
        self.call_counter = 0

        self.file_opts = {}
        self.file_opts['filetypes'] = [('Text Files', '.txt'),('CSV Files', '.csv'),('All Files', '.*')]
        self.file_opts['initialdir'] = 'C:\\Users\xxx\Documents'
        self.file_opts['title'] = 'File'

app = ApplicationUI()
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17466561/1639625 Also pretty much opinion-based.

Comment: How large and complex are those `create_canvas` etc. methods?

Comment: I think your question is too subjective. No, it's not a bad practice to wrap entire `tk` code to a single class, if you sufficient with this (_simple is better than complex_) and your class isn't just a variables bucket (_encapsulation_). But in some cases (if things started to be _complex_ or _repetative_) it's a good idea to create some classes, representing widgets (e.g. frame, toplevel) or another related objects.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

I'll check out that discussion that was linked.

Comment: @CommonSense
Thank you for the reassurance. I learned a bunch of techniques in OOP in the tutorial by Bernd Klein, but I never have had a chance to use them. I felt I was doing something wrong, because of this.

Comment: I think the key concept here is the balance of complexity and repetition in methods. I feel like I have it all under control again, noting the importance of these factors. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As mentioned in the comments this is a subjective matter or question
>   of trading-off pros and cons.

Anyhow there is a nice [pdf on clean code](http://aroma.vn/web/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/clean_code.pdf) which discusses some approaches and rules of thumb. There is also a whole chapter (10) on classes. So maybe this is a good place to start to get a feeling.